# Number of concurrent Big Query load jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am firing thousands of load jobs concurrently to different BigQuery tables. I see some of them to be executed instantly while others are queued. I was wondering how many load jobs can be run concurrently and if there is a way to run more of them instantaneously.

Comment: How long are the jobs on the queue? There is a limit of 1,000 load jobs per day. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas Do the jobs create a new table, or overwrite an existing table? More details please.

Comment: Some seconds/minutes, whereas some might be queued for couple of hours. For per project it's 50,000 per day. My load jobs append to existing tables (I doubt that matters though).

Answer (score 3):

As seen in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas), **the limit is 100 concurrent queries and to raise it you need to contact support or sales**:

> The following limits apply to query jobs created automatically by running interactive queries and to jobs submitted programmatically using jobs.query and query-type jobs.insert method calls.
>
> **Concurrent rate limit for on-demand, interactive queries — 100 concurrent queries**
>
> Queries with results that are returned from the query cache, and dry run queries do not count against this limit. You can specify a dry run query using the --dry_run flag or by setting the dryRun property in a query job.
>
> This limit is applied at the project level. **To raise the limit, contact support or contact sales.**

Comment: Are load jobs also considered queries?

Comment: Yes, both load and extract jobs are considered queries for quota purposes. I am certain of this information as I work in Google Cloud Platform Support.